# Spark Dataframe Write as Json works differently as Spark Data frame write as Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried converting CSV file to both JSON and Parquet  using spark. Am using aws EMR 5.10 with spark version 2.2

below is the sample code I have written for conversion to JSON

```
val data1 = sql("select * from csv_table")
data1.write.json("s3://sparktest/jsonout/")
```

When above piece of code is executed the Data is directly written in the s3 directory with files names as "part-000"

Next i have  tried parquet conversion

```
val data1 = sql("select * from csv_table")
data1.write.parquet("s3://sparktest/parquetout/")
```

Above Code when executed first created a temporary directly namely "_temporary" in the S3 output location and later on move files from the temporary location.

Why is dataframe write operation behaving differently in both cases ?

Comment: Does this behaviour cause any issues or you are just curious?

Comment: Sujit it doesnt cause any issue.  As our output storage is s3 writing to _temporary directory and then moving the files would take lot of time as move operation in s3 is not like HDFS rename. It needs to re-copy the data.

Comment: It's not behaving differently unless the json writer doesn't use Hadoop's FileOutputCommitter to write data. As to why the temporary? That same committer relies on rename() being an O(1) atomic operation capable of providing fast, robust commits. It's neither on S3